# Barcode scanner not found with Sample UWP app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp

I have a Honeywell Voyager 9520 (Model - Mk5145-31A38-I) which i am trying to make it work with the [Sample UWP](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner). I have tried all the modes in the scanner but nothing works. The app doesnt find the barcode at all.
I am on Windows 10 and VS2015 professional. I dont understand what is USB HID mode for this scanner. I am new to barcode scanner stuff. Any pointers in making it work would be highly appreciated.

I have downloaded the drivers from the "Software" tab from this Honeywell [link](https://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?category=hand-held-barcode-scanner&cat=HSM&pid=9520/40)

USBSerial.jpg is when i use USB Serial Emulation. USBKey.jpg is when i use USB Keyboard emulation.

**USBKey.jpg**
[image: USBKey.jpg]
**VS Code**
[image: VS Code]

**BarCode Manual**
[image: Barcode Manual]

**USB Serial**
[image: USB Serial]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hiddevice.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This GitHub sample uses the USB POS HID Scanner specification. From Device Manager screen capture it looks like this scanner doesn't support this.

> In addition to the devices listed, you can use barcode scanners from
>   various manufacturers that adhere to the USB HID POS Scanner
>   specification.

However the scanner does emulate a USB input device (keyboard), so you could use a normal TextBox to capture the scanner input for example.

Comment: Yes, when i open notepad and scan any code, it does work fine. Its just i wanted to avoid all the cursor focus and stuff. But how do i verify whether any barcode scanner is "USB POS HID Scanner specification". i have no clue about these things.

Comment: That would be a support question to the handset manufacturer: getting hold of data sheets/manuals should get you the information you need.

Comment: Talked to the support team of honeywell and they do have a specific USB hid pos scanner.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue but with a completely different cause. I'm using a webcam for barcode detection, which works quite well. However, after moving code from the sample app to a new project, I couldn't get it to work. The scanner object could not be created.

Turns out that the Package.appxmanifest Visual Studio 2015 UI does not show the necessary capability in the UI. It's simply not listed. I had to show Code for the Package.appxmanifest and then make sure DeviceCapability pointOfService was added, like so:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="pointOfService" /> <-- this one
  </Capabilities>
```

I got here through comparing the differences between the sample and my fresh project setup, and it took me a few hours (:sad face:) so I hope I can save someone else the effort by sharing this here.