# Getting this UWP sample app to work with a LS2208 Barcode Scanner

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, barcode-scanner

I have an LS2208 Motorla (Zebra) simple hand held scanner that I'd like get started working with a Windows 10 UWP. I downloaded this sample program
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner/cs

Its not picking up my handheld scanner-though I can plug it in and scan into a UWP textbox.
The sample app is failing here

```
 DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BarcodeScanner.GetDeviceSelector());
```

I installed the 64 bit Corescanner driver here
https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-windows.html

That didn't do anything-do I need to reboot my computer?
EDIT: Rebooted my computer, still doesn't work.

Comment: did you choose the connection mode? it's datasheet should contain settings barcodes. try the connection modes and the baud rates if you are using serial port.

Comment: https://www.mediaform.de/fileadmin/support/handbuecher/barcodescanner/sympol-motorola/Sym_LS2208_UG.pdf : starting from page 36

Comment: Its USB, not serial?

Comment: The sample program I listed isn't picking up the scanner-it works with a web app I use.

Comment: So maybe your scanner doesn't register itself as a barcode scanner, but rather as a regular keyboard. That would explain why it can scan into a text box, but doesn't show up in a barcode scanner search.

Comment: I found this similar question, but no satisfactory answers.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074253/barcode-scanner-not-found-with-sample-uwp-app

Answer (score 1):

I have the same scanner and from my research, the PointOfService namespace only works with USB.HID scanners and not regular USB keyboard emulators, see remarks: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt426649.aspx . That is why it does not find your scanner. I had the same problem. You should be able to get drivers for a serial port emulator (check your scanner manual) and monitor the port for incoming data from your scanner. Or check with Zebra if they can configure your scanner for USB.HID.

My problem is I am using Windows IoT and there are not a whole lot of drivers out there for that OS, i.e. the serial port emulator. So I am just using a textbox for scanner input.

Good luck.